jsPDF not converting Sublist marker in angular
I'm using CKeditor and it doesnot add any custom markers as far as i know. when i'm trying to download the div every styleing indentation is right except for the sublist marker which are replaced by %p bothe hollow circles and black fill squares only black circles are rendered in the pdf
<ul><li>Backend Springboot Developer<ul><li>Played a crucial role in developing Microservices apllication from scratch for our esteemed client At&amp;t</li><li>Created services for sending Emails, SMS , Dashboard &amp; USPS integration with our communication platform</li><li>Development, Deployment, Debugging and Updating were some my activites during this.&nbsp;</li><li>Used Spring boot with maven, JUNIT for testing, JAVA 11, SQL &amp; JPA</li></ul></li><li>Salesforce Tester<ul><li>Was a part of Gigapower a subsidary of At&amp;t</li><li>Learnt Omini Studio, LWC and Apex&nbsp;</li><li>Tested the API's using postman and dubbing for cause of the issue in the Salesforce sandbox</li></ul></li></ul>

above is my list code
Thanks in advance
enter image description here
This is how it getting represented in the pdfs

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
